# "No shape named X is known" where the shape is known and used elsewhere, when using \foreach loops

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

this is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}% For the example only, any class will do

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}% To get more advances positioning options
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}% To get more arrow heads
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,trees,hobby,calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block}=[rectangle, draw=black, rounded corners, ultra thick,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white, text width=1cm, text height=.3cm]
\tikzstyle{bblock}=[block, fill=blue!50]


\begin{tikzpicture}


%nodes
%   \pos = position
%   \lb = label
%   \t = text
\foreach \pos / \lb / \t in {
    (0,-1)/S1/$ $,
    (0,1)/S2/$ $,
%   
    (3,-2)/T1/$B$,
    (3,1)/T2/$ $,
%   
    (6,-3)/U1/$ $,
    (6,0)/U2/$B_{DP}$,
    (6,2)/U3/$ $,
%
    (9,-2.5)/V1/$ $,
    (9,-1)/V2/$ $,
    (9,1.5)/V3/$ $
    }
{
    \node[bblock] (\lb) at \pos {\t};
}

%arrows
\foreach \f/\t/\b in {
    S1/T1/0, 
    S2/T2/0,
    S2/T1/0,
    S1/T2/0,
    T1/U1/0,
    T1/U2/0,
    T2/U3/0,
    U1/V1/0,
    U2/V2/0,
    U2/V3/0,
    U3/V3/0
    }
{
    \draw[->, >=stealth', thick] (\f) edge[bend right=\b] (\t);
}

%in arrows
\foreach \t in {
    S1,
    S2
    }
{
    \draw[->, >=stealth', thick] ($ (\t) + (-1.5,.4) $) -- (\t);
    \draw[->, >=stealth', thick] ($ (\t) + (-1.5,-.4) $) -- (\t);
}

%out arrows
\foreach \t in {
    V1,
    V2,
    V3
    }
{
    \draw[->, >=stealth', thick] (\t) -- ($ (\t) + (1.5,.4) $);
    \draw[->, >=stealth', thick] (\t) -- ($ (\t) + (1.5,-.4) $);
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The last lines of each of the last foreach loops return a "no shape named X is known" where X is whatever shape appeared last in the list. If I add some other shapes, than they are recognized just fine.

Does anyone know why TikZ does this and how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the brace is written on the next line, which creates a spurious space. Just comment on the end of the line.

```
\documentclass{standalone}% For the example only, any class will do

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}% To get more advances positioning options
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}% To get more arrow heads
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,trees,hobby,calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block}=[rectangle, draw=black, rounded corners, ultra thick,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white, text width=1cm, text height=.3cm]
\tikzstyle{bblock}=[block, fill=blue!50]


\begin{tikzpicture}

%blob
\path[draw,green,fill=red,thick,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true, opacity=0.2]
(-.5,.3) .. (1.5,2.5) .. (2.8,3.6) .. (4,3) .. (4.2,0) .. (4,-3) 
.. (2.8,-3.6) .. (1.5,-2.5) .. (-.5,-.3)
;

\path[draw,red,fill=green,thick,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true, opacity=0.2]
(12.5,.3) .. (10.5,2.5) .. (9.2,3.6) .. (8,3) .. (7.8,0) .. (8,-3) 
.. (9.2,-3.6) .. (10.5,-2.5) .. (12.5,-.3)
;

\node[text=red] at (1.8,0) {\Huge S}; 
\node[text=green] at (10.2,0) {\Huge T}; 

%nodes
%   \pos = position
%   \lb = label
%   \t = text
\foreach \pos / \lb / \t in {
    (0,-1)/S1/$ $,
    (0,1)/S2/$ $,
%   
    (3,-2)/T1/$B$,
    (3,1)/T2/$ $,
%   
    (6,-3)/U1/$ $,
    (6,0)/U2/$B_{DP}$,
    (6,2)/U3/$ $,
%
    (9,-2.5)/V1/$ $,
    (9,-1)/V2/$ $,
    (9,1.5)/V3/$ $
    }
{
    \node[bblock] (\lb) at \pos {\t};
}

%arrows
\foreach \f/\t/\b in {
    S1/T1/0, 
    S2/T2/0,
    S2/T1/0,
    S1/T2/0,
    T1/U1/0,
    T1/U2/0,
    T2/U3/0,
    U1/V1/0,
    U2/V2/0,
    U2/V3/0,
    U3/V3/0
    }
{
    \draw[->, >=stealth', thick] (\f) edge[bend right=\b] (\t);
}

%in arrows
\foreach \t in {%
    S1,
    S2% comment to avoid spurious space
    }
{
    \draw[->, >=stealth', thick] ($ (\t) + (-1.5,.4) $) -- (\t);
    \draw[->, >=stealth', thick] ($ (\t) + (-1.5,-.4) $) -- (\t);
}

%out arrows
\foreach \t in {
    V1,
    V2,
    V3% comment to avoid spurious space
    }
{
    \draw[->, >=stealth', thick] (\t) -- ($ (\t) + (1.5,.4) $);
    \draw[->, >=stealth', thick] (\t) -- ($ (\t) + (1.5,-.4) $);
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: spurious]

Comment: They weren't kidding when they said Tikz is finicky... Thanks for your help

Comment: @ShaiDeshe Tikz is difficult, it's true but much less than TeX. Spurious spaces are a problem of TeX that arises with Tikz, because Tikz is written in TeX.

Comment: @AndréC +1 but no problem with spurious spaces with `\xintFor`... that said, the problem with spaces is purely on the user side, as the vast majority of LaTeX users do not make the effort to understand the general rules regarding spaces in TeX. (admittedly even knowing the rules is not always enough of course because macros can change the general expectations by using math mode in disguise for example).

Comment: @jfbu I didn't know xinttools. It would be interesting if you could give us a solution to this problem here with `\xintFor`.

Comment: It would be `\xintForthree #1#2#3 in {(S1, T1, 0), (S2, T2, 0), (U3, V3, 0)}\do{...stuff with #1, #2, #3...}`. Spaces are trimmed automatically at start and end. The syntax is perhaps not as agreeable as with `\foreach` (I preferred standard math notation with n-uples, which is in fact more complex to implement than `/` as separators). I don't think I will add a solution, because yours is perfect for `\foreach` and it is natural for everyone except me to use `\foreach` when TikZifying.

Comment: @jfbu I regret this because I think that if you gave an example of how to use your package, it would interest many people and make it easier for everyone to learn. :)

Comment: thanks, really. But I have already made many many answer using `\xintFor` so I hesitate adding to the advertisement... (I will do perhaps nevertheless later today if I find time...).

Comment: @AndréC done...

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it with `\xintFor` (from package [`xinttools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint)) : it trims spaces of items (leading and trailing) so no such issue as analyzed by @AndréC can arise.

On the other hand the syntax of list of n-uples adds a complication when an n-nuple has elements which themselves are n-uples. Here 3-uples whose first components are couples. We must hide the latter in braces.

`\xintFor` does not nice functionalities of `\foreach` such as `1, 2, ..., 10` syntax.

It does not use groups and does not use macros for holding values.

It has also been especially designed to be usable to generate rows in tabulars.

```
\documentclass{standalone}% For the example only, any class will do

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}% To get more advances positioning options
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}% To get more arrow heads
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,trees,hobby,calc}

\usepackage{xinttools}% \xintFor trims spaces...

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block}=[rectangle, draw=black, rounded corners, ultra thick,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white, text width=1cm, text height=.3cm]
\tikzstyle{bblock}=[block, fill=blue!50]

\begin{tikzpicture}

%blob
\path[draw,green,fill=red,thick,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true, opacity=0.2]
(-.5,.3) .. (1.5,2.5) .. (2.8,3.6) .. (4,3) .. (4.2,0) .. (4,-3) 
.. (2.8,-3.6) .. (1.5,-2.5) .. (-.5,-.3)
;

\path[draw,red,fill=green,thick,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true, opacity=0.2]
(12.5,.3) .. (10.5,2.5) .. (9.2,3.6) .. (8,3) .. (7.8,0) .. (8,-3) 
.. (9.2,-3.6) .. (10.5,-2.5) .. (12.5,-.3)
;

\node[text=red] at (1.8,0) {\Huge S}; 
\node[text=green] at (10.2,0) {\Huge T}; 

%nodes
%   #1 (= \pos) = position
%   #2 (= \lb) = label
%   #3 (= \t) = text
%\foreach \pos / \lb / \t in {
%    (0,-1)/S1/$ $,
\xintForthree #1#2#3 in {% list of 3-tuples
% we *must* hide the parentheses and commas used inside individual
% components of the 3-tuple
    (  {(0,-1)}  , S1  , $ $  ), 
    (  {(0,1)}   , S2  , $ $  ),
%   
    (  {(3,-2)}  , T1  , $B$  ),
    (  {(3,1)}   , T2  , $ $  ),
%   
    ({(6,-3)},  U1,  $ $      ),
    ({(6,0)} ,  U2,  $B_{DP}$  ),
    ({(6,2)} ,  U3,  $ $      ),
%
    ({(9,-2.5)},   V1,  $ $    ),
    ({(9,-1)}  ,   V2,  $ $    ),
    ({(9,1.5)} ,   V3,  $ $    )
    }
\do
{
%   \node[bblock] (\lb) at \pos {\t};
    \node[bblock] (#2) at #1 {#3};
% for checking if spaces go trimmed
% \typeout{\detokenize{#1--#2--#3++}}%
}

%arrows
%\foreach \f/\t/\b in {
\xintForthree #1 #2 #3 in {
    (S1, T1, 0), 
    (S2, T2, 0),
    (S2, T1, 0),
    (S1, T2, 0),
    (T1, U1, 0),
    (T1, U2, 0),
    (T2, U3, 0),
    (U1, V1, 0),
    (U2, V2, 0),
    (U2, V3, 0),
    (U3, V3, 0)
    }
\do
{
    \draw[->, >=stealth', thick] (#1) edge[bend right=#3] (#2);
}

%in arrows (no problem with end of line space)
\xintFor #1 in {%
    S1,
    S2
    }
\do
{
    \draw[->, >=stealth', thick] ($ (#1) + (-1.5,.4) $) -- (#1);
    \draw[->, >=stealth', thick] ($ (#1) + (-1.5,-.4) $) -- (#1);
}

%out arrows (no problem with end of line space)
\xintFor #1 in {
    V1,
    V2,
    V3
    }
\do
{
    \draw[->, >=stealth', thick] (#1) -- ($ (#1) + (1.5,.4) $);
    \draw[->, >=stealth', thick] (#1) -- ($ (#1) + (1.5,-.4) $);
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

In `\xintForthree` one can use `#1#2#3` or `#1 #2 #3`. But there is no `#1/#2/#3` syntax which however could arguably be added at some point...